# Not able to install any package on SUSE 11

Tags: linux, perl, suse

For some reason I need to use SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (i586)  distro with SP2. I need to install package named swig on it.

Every time I install or update any package I get this error message:

```
File '/repodata/repomd.xml' not found on medium 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/perl/SLE_11/'
```

Here is the list of added repos in my case:

```
%zypper lr

# | Alias                          | Name                                                                        | Enabled | Refresh
--+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------
1 | devel_languages_perl           | perl modules (SLE_11)                                                       | Yes     | No     
2 | devel_languages_python         | Python Modules (openSUSE_Factory)                                           | Yes     | No     
3 | devel_languages_python_Factory | Development versions of Python interpreters and other stuff (openSUSE_12.2) | Yes     | No     
4 | devel_tools_scm                | Software configuration management (SLE_11_SP2)                              | Yes     | No
```

Can anybody please point me to the right direction. This is my first day on SUSE.

Answer (score 0):

Come on, you're not even trying to figure this out.

I have (to the best of my knowledge) *never* used Suse. However, the helpful error message gives you a URL. I pasted that into my web-browser and found it is indeed unavailable. Moving up the directory tree lets me see that the start is OK, and poking around suggests that you want it to read `.../perl/SLE_11_SP3` at the end.

The "SP3" suggests you want to have service-pack 3 installed to continue using the official repositories.